# How to make text to appear into image box?

Tags: html, css

I started to make my own gallery, and have one thing that cant resolve..

I want text that appear in part "UNSEREN DIENSTLEISTUNGEN" from homepage, from left in this [site](http://jungbedachungen.com/), to be showed in similar way in other images, but with image style like other pages (sppinin images).

This is code from first image:

```
<div class="serviceQuad">
    <div class="tr-slideImgOut"><img src="/files/hjung2014/img/holzbau.jpg"  alt="Holzbau" /></div>
    <span class="figure tr-slideIn" href="">{{insert_content::26}}</span></div>
```

and this is image style from other images, (like i want to be, but text to appear inside box)

```
<div class="serviceQuad">
    <div class="morph"><img src="/files/hjung2014/img/holzbau.jpg"  alt="Holzbau" /></div>
    <span class="morph" href="">{{insert_content::26}}</span></div>
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add class with changed rotation style.

For example add `fullRotate` class like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="serviceQuad">
    <div class="tr-slideImgOut fullRotate">
        <img src="/files/hjung2014/img/holzbau.jpg" alt="Holzbau" />
    </div>
    <span class="figure tr-slideIn" href="">{{insert_content::26}}</span>
</div>
```

And then add new rotation style for it:

**CSS**

```
.serviceQuad:hover .tr-slideImgOut.fullRotate img {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
  transform: rotate(360deg)
}
```

Comment: Many Thanks !! Your sollution worked like a sharm. :)